# how to use scipy.ndimage.convolve for a given stencil?

Tags: numpy, scipy, convolution

I need to do something very similar to what is detailed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854522/nested-loop-with-array-indexing-in-numpy). But the way the stencils are done are not obvious to me... well the stencil for `_flux` is, but the ones for `temp_bz` & `temp_bx` are not.

I think the picture would get clearer with variables, instead of numbers (something like `stencil = np.array([[a, b], [c, d]])` with `a=0.5, b=...`
As example, if the recurrence relation is

```
flux2[i,j] = a*flux2[i-1,j] + b*bz[i-1,j]*dx + c*flux2[i,j-1] - d*bx[i,j-1]*dz
```

how the code would be changed ?

Answer (score 1):

Having `flux2`, `bz` and `bx` variables, and assuming they are numpy arrays (if they are not, they should), you could write that ecuation in a vectorized form as follows:

```
flux2[1:,1:] = a * flux2[:-1,1:] + b * bz[:-1,1:] * dx + c * flux2[1:,:-1] - d * bx[1:,:-1] * dz
```

Note that, since you didn't mention `dz`, I assumed it is a constant, if it is a matrix of the same shape as `flux2`, replace with `dz[1:, 1:]` (same applies to `dx`).

That line above will vectorize the operation to every `i,j` of the matrix, and thus, remove the `for` loop, giving a considerable speedup.

You would have to define the boundary conditions for row and column `0`, as your equation doesn't define what to do in those special cases.

So, in short, as your *stencil* only uses one position for each variable, and only has 4 interactions, I would say is way faster to calculate it in its analytic form, rather than convolving 3 images with almost all-0 stencils (which would be quite a lot of overkill).